# Multiply/Divide Floats Produce Double?

Tags: casting, floating-point, double, nstimeinterval, cgfloat

In Objective-C (or C), if I do

```
CGFloat distance = 215;
CGFloat velocity = 20;
NSTimeInterval time = distance / velocity;
```

is that correct? Or, should I cast either `distance` or `velocity` to `NSTimeInterval`?

Note, in iOS 7.0:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;

typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

Comment: A mention of a programming language would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will divide the two values and produce the mathematical quotient rounded to a `CGFloat`. Then it will convert that `CGFloat` to an `NSTimeInterval` (which does not change the value) and store it in `time`.

If the `CGFloat` result is accurate enough for your needs (even when it is `float`), then the code is fine. If it is not, then you should convert one of the operands to `NSTimeInterval`, which will result in the quotient being rounded to an `NSTimeInterval` instead of a `CGFloat`.

If an `NSTimeInterval` result is not accurate enough, then you need alternative code.